# Midpoint of chord of contact

Tags: geometry, circles

Question:
The locus of the mid-point of the chord of contact of tangents drawn from points lying on the straight line $4x - 5y = 20$ to the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 9$ is:

a) $20(x^2 - y^2)- 36x + 45y = 0$

b) $20(x^2 + y^2)+ 36x - 45y = 0$

c) $36(x^2 + y^2)- 20x + 45y = 0$

d) $36(x^2 + y^2)+ 20x - 45y = 0$

How would I even start this question? Please give me a hint!

Comment: Your question would be improved by including the following: (1) What is the geometry? (I did enough of a diagram to see that the line and the circle don't intersect; you should either include a diagram, or at least describe it.) (2) I'm not familiar with the the phrase "contact of tangents." Does that mean "pick a point on the line, and draw the two tangents  to the circle which pass through it?

Comment: @Semiclassical Well a chord of contact is basically a chord running through the point of contacts of the two tangents from an exterior point.

Comment: Ok. Sketch it out: do you notice anything interesting about the exterior point, the midpoint, and the center of circle?

Comment: Ummmmm...... Should I draw it accurately? I don't think the line and the circle intersect, they might be tangential at some point though.

Comment: I agree, though it'd be best if you can find a simple way to confirm this. What I was getting at is that, if you pick an exterio point and draw the tangents, then the midpoint of the chord of tangents is collinear to with the center of the circle and the exterior point. (Do you see why?)

Comment: Ohhhh, I see that now. That's a good observation o.O

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16750/discussion-between-semiclassical-and-gummy-bears).

Comment: @Semiclassical Very very sorry. I had to go somewhere at that time. Are you still free?

Answer (score 2):

None of a), b), c) or d) (as written) is the answer.

By using the dotted $3-4-5$ triangle in the picture below, you can capture a convenient point on the locus, then test it in the various equations. The point $E$ in this picture is at $(9/5,0)$, which *happens* to be on $20(x^2 - y^2)- 36x + 45y = 0$.

If you compute the point $F$ using a similar strategy, you'll find that this point is $(0,-9/4)$ is *not* on $a)$. However, both points lie on $20(x^2 + y^2)- 36x + 45y = 0$. I guess you typoed $a)$.

In the graph, the smaller circle is my suggested fix for a).

[image: diagram of the situation]

It's not very tough to work out what transformations like this look like. Take a look at this diagram, viewed as being in $\Bbb C$, where $A$ is the origin:

[image]

Since $\triangle ACZ$ and $\triangle ACE$ are similar, $|AE|=|AC|\frac{|AC|}{|AZ|}$. In our situation, we may as well start confusing segment lengths for complex norms and write $|AZ|=|Z|$ and $|AC|=3$, so $|AE|=\frac{9}{|Z|}$. To get $E$, we can normalize $Z$ and multiply by the length $|AE|$ to get $\frac{9}{|Z|}\frac{Z}{|Z|}=\frac{9Z}{|Z|^2}$.

The map $Z\mapsto \frac{9Z}{|Z|^2}$ is a [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobius_transformation) of the complex plane, and as such it will carry the given line onto a circle contained inside the circle radius $3$. It is also its own inverse function.

At the very worst, you can deduce the equation of the circle from the two points given above along with $(0,0)$.

But let's do better and deduce the equation! Let $m$ be the Möbius transformation above. Then if $(x,y)$ lie in the locus, $m(x+iy)$ lies on the given line, and therefore $m(x+iy)$ has to satisfy $4x-5iy=20$. In terms of $\Bbb R^2$, the transformation maps $(x,y)$ to $(\frac{9x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{9y}{x^2+y^2})$. To satisfy $4x-5y=20$, we have:

$$4(\frac{9x}{x^2+y^2})-5(\frac{9y}{x^2+y^2})=20$$

Rewriting:

$$4(9x)-5(9y)=20(x^2+y^2)\\ 36x-45y=20(x^2+y^2)\\ 0=20(x^2+y^2)-36x+45y$$

In standard form: $(x-\frac{9}{10})^2+(y+\frac{9}{8})^2 =\frac{3321}{1600}$

Answer (score 0):

Centre of circle is origin O. Get equation of line L' through O perpendicular to given line L, and hence intersection points of L' with circle and L. Hence check L does not intersect circle. The midpoint of the chord is *inside* the circle, so the locus is bounded, so it cannot be (a).

Locus passes through O (points at infinity on L give the chord as a diameter), and comes close to the intersection point P of L and L'. (b), (c), (d) are all circles, so locus is a circle. By symmetry its centre should lie on OP and be close to the midpoint of OP. It is easy to read off the coordinates of the centre of the circles (b), (c), (d) and hence to conclude which must be correct.